# How do I get data from a content type field into a view?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a client who wants to be able to put a custom header on certain views. However, I don't want to give him access to edit the view header, so I've put a field in a content type that is being used for the view with the machine name `field_related_content_title`.

The machine name for the content type used is `landing_page`, and the view's machine name is `related_content`.

I'm not quite sure how to make this work. I have the basic idea, that I would use a hook in template.php (but not at all sure which one to use), and I'm sure my logic is faulty.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried using `<h2 class="title">
<?php
echo variable_get('field_related_content_title');
?>
</h2>` in a Global PHP header, and while the h2 prints to the page, the result is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the view in order to have a header (Custom text, por example). Then, in your module you can use the hook views_pre_render:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    $view->header['area_text_custom']->options['content'] = $view->result[0]->field_related_content_title[0]['rendered'];
}
```

This will put the value of the field_related_content_title field (for the first views result) in the header of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can show this field value in the same way you show the other fields. If you are using views ui, put `field_related_content_title` as the first field (using hide if empty, if you want).

Comment: I tried that, but that puts the related content field for each view item, but not in the header where I need it.

Answer (score -2):

My answer is a question: does this view show only one item (landing_page), or multiple?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Answer cannot be a question, sorry.

Comment: I didn't know that, but I cannot comment, since I am newbie. :) Thank you!